# Using Wildcards to Search Arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, wildcard, element

I'm wondering if it is possible to create an array of elements and then create an event listener using a wildcard that will trigger when any of these elements are interacted with. A sample of what this might look like:

```
var e = new Array();
e[1] = document.getElementById('some-element');
e[2] = document.getElementById('some-other-element');

e.onmouseup = function() {
  if(e == e[1]) {
    //Some code here
  } else if (e == e[2]) {
    //Some code here
  } 
}
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` method instead of element property (`onmouseup`)

Comment: @hindmost: I'm not aware that arrays support `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Felix Kling No need of such support. Just iterate over the array of elements and apply `addEventListener`

Comment: @hindmost: That wasn't clear from your first comment.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes, but it was just a note, not a solution

Comment: I agree, it looks like OP is trying to delegate event to common parent, and have only one event handler to rule them all.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The title seems to indicate that you're trying to find all the elements in the document whose IDs match a certain pattern (although it actually says "search an array"...)? But the content of your question seems to be about  setting listeners on a set of elements whose IDs you already know. Or is it both--you want to find the elements using a wildcard, and then set an event listener on all of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really `wildcard` but something that would allow you to bind only one event handler for all elements - event delegation:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target == e[1]) {
        //Some code here
        alert('some-element');
    } else if (target == e[2]) {
        //Some code here
        alert('some-other-element');
    }
}, false);
```

This works due to the fact that event bubbles up the DOM tree until it reaches `body` where it's detected, and from there necessary action is dispatched.

Here is a demo with this approach: **http://jsfiddle.net/jwoxnn3d/**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "wildcard", but the short answer is: no, it's not.

You have to iterate over the array and bind the handler to each element. Inside the handler you can use `this` to refer to the element the handler is bound to.